# Where Should Images Be Stored In A .NET Project?

Tags: .net

If you are using Maven with Java it has the convention of separate directories for classes and resources.
e.g.

> src - main - java
>     src - main - resources

All my source code would go in the first directory (well sub-directories due to packages) and images, xml files etc would go in the second directory.

Is there a convention for .NET Desktop application projects?

e.g.

Just put everything flat in the same directory as the project file.

Or put the code flat and the images in a sub-directory called Images.

Something else?

Comment: Put them *where it makes sense to you* (sometimes the path might be slightly dictated, such as when designing SharePoint solutions). I think it is *very sloppy* to shove everything in one directory. Just because it can be done, doesn't mean it should be done.

Comment: This question was about _conventions_ not _where it makes sense to me_.

Comment: Embedded resource is another option. If you don't have too many images to contain, it may work for you - to have a single EXE file with everything in in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard convention, but there exist some "best practices" for code readability & maintainability.

For example, you may create a folder with name "images", and add  all of your application images in it. This will enhance code organization by having a folder containing the images.

You may also create sub-directories inside "images" folder, based on modules you have in the app., and you may also have a common folders which contains the common images in all modules.

For instance, if you have 3 main modules: login, main & settings, and each have separate images and some common images. then you may create these folders:

1. Images/Common
2. Images/Settings
3. Images/Login
4. Images/Main

Some developers also prefer to put this folder "Images" inside another folder with name "resources", where resources contains many folders like "images", "xml", "data" ... etc. i.e it contains all resources which you need in runtime, this is a good practice too.

Using the same example above, the hierarchy will be:

1. Resources/Images/Common
2. Resources/Images/Settings
3. Resources/Images/Login
4. Resources/Images/Main

This will be more organized and will enhance readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the best place to put them is in an `images` folder inside the root of the application. So if your path is `C:\NETProjects\ApplicationName` you would create a directory under `ApplicationName`

This way when a image resource is referenced in the code its always `/images/nameofile`.